# get_user_meta is not working after WP_User_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using get_user_meta() function in a custom template, where i need to fetch all the users data and their meta, I am using WP_User_Query to fetch the set of users and after that i want to get all the custom meta information for every users (in the loop), but somehow get_user_meta($userId) function returning blank array if I used this function after the Wp_user_Query, whereas If I place get_user_meta(<some_id>) before the WP_User_Query function then it is giving all the meta information for that user_id I supplied for.
Here is the code:

```
function get_users_lists(){
$export_user_args = array(
                    'role__in' => array('alumnus', 'fellow'),
                    'exclude' => array(7, 60),
                    'orderby' => 'user_login',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                 );
            
            
            
            $export_user_lists = new WP_User_Query($export_user_args);
            $userMeta = get_user_meta(5884);
                    
            print_r($userMeta); exit;
            return $userMeta;
}
```

Above code is not working it is giving me an empty array for meta information. In the below code I am getting all the user_meta information.

```
function get_users_lists(){
$export_user_args = array(
                    'role__in' => array('alumnus', 'fellow'),
                    'exclude' => array(7, 60),
                    'orderby' => 'user_login',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                 );
            
            
            $userMeta = get_user_meta(5884);
                    
            print_r($userMeta); exit;

            $export_user_lists = new WP_User_Query($export_user_args);
            return $userMeta;
}
```

can anyone help me into this problem, I am stuck from last 3 days but did not find any clue on this.

Comment: I see you do ```print_r($userMeta); exit;``` Are you sure you are getting an empty array or is perhaps something throwing an error? What is logging if you try to print_r the $export_user_lists?

Comment: Yes @Jelmer if i am using get_user_meta() before the wp_user_query then it is giving me all the usermeta for the user id 5884, but if change code a bit and use get_user_meta() after the wp_user_query function then i am getting blank array of user meta. and one more thing i want to mention here I am trying to get usersmeta in wp_ajax function.

Comment: and it does not showing any error in the log as well. and here is the complete code is shared: https://justpaste.it/ab0wp